# Unable to install and open cryptocurrency wallet

Tags: software-installation

Hi I am trying to very simply install and use the exodus wallet on my raspberry pi.

I have the default OS installed, and downloaded the .zip from [here](https://www.exodus.io/releases/).

I extracted the files, but when double-clicking on Exodus and selecting 'Execute' All that happens is a blank text file is created in that folder with the name `��Y@PQ�@8`

I had the exact same problem when trying the same process with jaxx wallet.

Does anyone know how I can overcome this annoying problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The release file on that page is for x86 64 bit architecture. Raspberry Pi is arm architecture. So, it wouldn't support the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: thanks ameer, I am totally new to both linux and crypto wallets so this is super helpful to me